# how to remove the border of the last item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this structure:

```
<div id="results">
     <div class="post-item">
         <div class="post-item-inside"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="post-item">
         <div class="post-item-inside"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="post-item">
         <div class="post-item-inside"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="post-item">
         <div class="post-item-inside"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="post-item">
         <div class="post-item-inside"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The `CSS`:

```
.post-item {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.post-item-inside {
    width: 95%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #d0d1d5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And I want to delete the border color of the last `.post-item-inside`. I have tried this method:

```
.post-item:last-child .post-item-inside {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Given the code provided, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/z3u5f/ - you may have conflicting CSS or the HTML isnt representative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code using `border-top` and `first-child`:

```
.post-item {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.post-item-inside {
    width: 95%;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-color: #d0d1d5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#results .post-item:first-child .post-item-inside {
    border-top: none;
}
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Although your code works fine, try this instead :

```
#results .post-item:last-child .post-item-inside {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Maybe you have other `.post-item` elements in your website more than those in the `#results`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine.

```
.post-item:last-child .post-item-inside {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w4x7m/)